# Hi! I want to make my program display periodically pieces of text. Something as a "loading bar".

Tags: c++, time, timer

my name is Alvaro and I'm programming in c++ with notepad++ and cygwin (on windows).

I want to make a "loading bar" for my program. I don't intend to do it a real loading bar, only pieces of text appearing every x seconds.

I was thinking if there was some function in c++ that could hold commands given amount of time.

If the IS a way of making a real loading bar (realize commands while the main process is being executed)

This is the piece of code in which I want to apply any of these functions. Its a simple print command, and I'd want it to display each colon every x seconds:

`cout <<":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"<<endl;
cout << endl;`

Thanks for your answer and please keep it the simpler you can :).

Comment: So you're not doing anything while displaying it, just sleeping in between each bit?

Comment: The way to do this depends on what progress you're trying to measure..

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << ":";
cout.flush();
```

By flushing the stream after every write, the text should appear immediately without needing a newline.